# Plivo API Create subaccount, cant enable the subaccount

Tags: node.js, plivo

Using the [Plivo API](https://api-reference.plivo.com/latest/node/resources/subaccount/create-a-subaccount), I am able to create a subaccount, however the subaccount remains disabled. I can't see what I am doing wrong, either the docs are wrong or there is a bug in the API. It seems like `enabled: true` does not do anything. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
var plivo = require('plivo');
var plivoclient = new plivo.Client(auth_id, auth_token);
plivoclient.subAccounts.create("subaccount name", {
     enabled: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following

```
plivoclient.subAccounts.create("subaccount name", {enabled: true})
```

With

```
plivoclient.subAccounts.create("subaccount name", true)
```

Ref: https://github.com/plivo/plivo-node/blob/master/lib/resources/accounts.js#L118